# Make a calculation with aliases in one (sub)query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with data and am trying to make the following calculation in a query: IDO / IDP * 100.

```
**TBL**
Name    IDP    IDO
ABC     123    231
DEF     124    NULL
GHI     125    NULL
JKL     126    342
KNM     127    NULL
```

I managed to count up all the values needed to make the calculation and gave each an alias. This is what I have so far, but the calculation part returns an error telling me the references are not supported.

```
SELECT
    SUM(case when IDP is not null then 1 end) as Checked,
    SUM(case when IDO is null then 1 end) as NotChecked,
        (SELECT Checked / NotChecked) * 100 AS Result
FROM TBL
```

I've also tried with a subquery, but it results in the same error.

```
SELECT
        SUM(case when IDP is not null then 1 end) as Checked,
        SUM(case when IDO is null then 1 end) as NotChecked,
            (
              SELECT Checked / NotChecked * 100 AS Result FROM TBL
            )
        FROM TBL
```

What would be the right or a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to reference aliases created in a `SELECT` clause in that same `SELECT` clause.

As you probably know, you could just repeat the logic, like the following (although I assume the purpose of your question is to avoid writing the logic twice).

```
SELECT
    SUM(case when IDP is not null then 1 end) as Checked,
    SUM(case when IDO is null then 1 end) as NotChecked,
        (SUM(case when IDP is not null then 1 end) / SUM(case when IDO is null then 1 end)) * 100 AS Result
FROM TBL
```

A subquery version, where you don't repeat the logic, would be the following. Note that the aliases are created in the subquery so the outer query has no trouble referencing them.

```
SELECT
 Checked, NotChecked, (Checked / NotChecked) * 100 as Result
FROM
(
 SELECT
    SUM(case when IDP is not null then 1 end) as Checked,
    SUM(case when IDO is null then 1 end) as NotChecked
 FROM TBL 
) tt
```

Since you don't seem to be summing, just counting null/non-null values, I personally find the sum/case statements a bit confusing and might prefer something like this:

```
SELECT
 Checked, NotChecked, (Checked / NotChecked) * 100 as Result
FROM
(
 SELECT
    count(IDP) as Checked,
    count(*)-count(IDO) as NotChecked
 FROM TBL 
) tt
```

Comment: Thanks! Very useful and detailed, and you were right about the case statements being a bit confusing. I ended up using your version, I was struggling using COUNT to count up NULL values, but it all works out now. Appreciate it